# Error on installing NoRedInk/elm-decode-pipeline with Elm 0.19.1

Tags: elm

I'm working through an example on elmprogramming.com and am stuck on installing the `elm-decode-pipeline` package.  Specifically when I

```
elm install NoRedInk/elm-decode-pipeline
```

I get the following message

```
-- CANNOT FIND COMPATIBLE VERSION ------------------------------------- elm.json

I cannot find a version of NoRedInk/elm-decode-pipeline that is compatible with
your existing dependencies.
```

Perhaps this is because Elm moved from 0.19.0 to 0.19.1?  Or perhaps I'm doing something wrong?  My `elm.json` is

```
{
    "type": "application",
    "source-directories": [
        "src"
    ],
    "elm-version": "0.19.1",
    "dependencies": {
        "direct": {
            "elm/browser": "1.0.2",
            "elm/core": "1.0.2",
            "elm/html": "1.0.0",
            "elm/http": "2.0.0",
            "elm/json": "1.1.3"
        },
        "indirect": {
            "elm/bytes": "1.0.8",
            "elm/file": "1.0.5",
            "elm/time": "1.0.0",
            "elm/url": "1.0.0",
            "elm/virtual-dom": "1.0.2"
        }
    },
    "test-dependencies": {
        "direct": {},
        "indirect": {}
    }
}
```

What should I do to install the package?  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just moved. The package is now at `NoRedInk/elm-json-decode-pipeline`.

You definitely can't be blamed for being confused though. There is no indication of this in the package documentation, only in the description of the source code repository, and there's also no indication that the old package only works with 0.18. Unfortunately this is just the state of the package ecosystem at the moment, and fixing it does not seem to have much priority.

The best way to make sure you have a package that works for 0.19 is to search for it on the package site. Everything that pops up there should work for 0.19, as you have to use a different search for 0.18 packages.